# Looping OPENROWSET statements based on file folder contents

Tags: sql-server, loops, openrowset

Our SQL Server (2014) has a variable number of uniform `.XLSX`  files dropped in it daily. Any given day, there could be a variable number of 5-20 files with various file names. Thankfully, They all have the exact same headers, and tab names.

I've already written a `xp_cmdshell` command, to ingest a list of all the filenames, staged in a Temporary table, along with a sequence number.

Is there a way I can use Dynamic SQL to "loop" through importing all the files through `OPENROWSET`?

The final output would contain 1 table containing the contents of all the XLSX files.

Here's a temp table that mimics the filenames that's loaded in it:

```
CREATE TABLE #FILENAMES (FILE_NME VARCHAR(100), SEQ INT ) 
INSERT INTO #FILENAMES  
VALUES
  ('WeeklyReport_20201207.xlsx',1),
('WeeklyReport_20201213.xlsx',2),
('WeeklyReport_20201214.xlsx',3),
('WeeklyReport_20201220.xlsx',4)
```

And here's the Dynamtc SQL/Loop I've already started.

```
DECLARE @FILE_NME NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'WeeklyReport_20201220.xlsx'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''MSDASQL'', ''DRIVER={MICROSOFT EXCEL DRIVER (*.XLS, *.XLSX, *.XLSM, *.XLSB)}; DBQ=D:\FILES\'+@FILE_NME+''', ''SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$]'') T1'

DECLARE @COUNTER INT;
SET @COUNTER = 0;

WHILE @COUNTER <= 2
BEGIN
EXEC (@SQL )

   SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1;
END;
```

Comment: **Please** do this client-side. T-SQL is not the place to do this from. Can SSIS not do this for you? There is cracking code for `SqlBulkCopy` out there also

Comment: Hi @Charlieface - We don't have SSIS enabled. Outside of our control!

Comment: It's really easy to just `STRING_AGG` all the `openrowset`s together with a `union all`. But I still think you should do this client-side. Can you not do C#, PHP, anything? Just don't enable `xp_cmdshell`, and don't `openrowset` from Excel.

Comment: Thanks! Howevr STRING_AGG doesn't work with SQL Server 2014. I don't have any knowledge of C# or PHP. Openrowset is very efficient for us and rarely gives us issues. XP_CMDSHELL is already enabled for my profile.

Comment: Then the usual `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()', nvarchar(max))` there are hundreds of examples online. Make sure to `PRINT @SQL` before you try run it.